# Vuetify / vuejs links not working in item list

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have passed in the following data via a prop to a component holding a v-list item component. I have the list rendered along with the link text but for some reason, the links aren't actually functional for some reason. What have I done wrong?

Data:

```js
data() {
    return {
      categories: [
        {
          src: 'https://picsum.photos/200',
          title: 'Pic 1',
          links: [
            { text: 'GOOGLE', url: 'https://www.google.co.uk/' },
            { text: 'Link 2', url: '#' },
            { text: 'Link 3', url: '#' },
            { text: 'Link 4', url: '#' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
```

Component:

```js
<template>
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="6" md="3" v-for="p in picture" :key="p.id">
      <v-hover v-slot:default="{ hover }">
        <v-img :src="p.src">
          <v-expand-transition>
            <div
              v-if="hover"
              class="transition-fast-in-fast-out red darken-2 v-card--reveal white--text text-center"
              style="height: 100%;"
            >
              <v-list-item-group>
                <v-list-item v-for="link in p.links" :key="link.id">
                  <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title :to="link.url">{{
                      link.text
                    }}</v-list-item-title>
                  </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list-item-group>
            </div>
          </v-expand-transition>
        </v-img>
      </v-hover>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this **:to** prop refers to a route component declaration and not external urls.

For redirecting to external url you can use something like below.

```
<v-list-item :href="link.url" target="_blank">{{link.text}}</v-list-item>
```

Comment: You need to set the link on <v-list-item> component